# WP8: Get tab position in maps control

Tags: maps, windows-phone-8

For a Microsoft.Phone.Maps control, how can I get the position (geocoordinates?) of the tap when the user taps on the map?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Tap event handler, and use the GestureEventArgument to get the screen position. See [Map tap event / mouse down event in windows phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716289/map-tap-event-mouse-down-event-in-windows-phone-8)

Now that you have the screen position use Map.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.convertviewportpointtogeocoordinate