# How to place popup next to pushpin

Tags: windows-phone-8, popup, maps

I want to give a popup dialog when the user click on a pushpin on the maps in my app, however I want to place the popup next to the pushpin, as you move around the map it should stay there? How would I do this? My code is very basic so far, simply add a map to the app on startup get the current location and then add a blue circle to that location, then I gave the circle a tap event, on the tap event I showed my usercontrol as a popup?

my code so far:

```
  void myCircle_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup popup;
        popup = new Popup();
        popup.Child = new moreDetails();
        popup.VerticalOffset = 100;
        popup.HorizontalOffset = 50;
        popup.IsOpen = true;

    }
```

thanx

Comment: You don't appear to be looking at the `GestureEventArgs` for *where* the tap happendeD?

Comment: so would I be able to use the gesture information to determine the vertical offset and horizontal offset, and if I use this will it remain at that specific location eventhough the map zooms out and moves around? im not sure

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13716289/50447

Comment: @RowlandShaw you don't need to get the gesture info on the map. You just need to add your "popup" to the layer with your push pin. Then, when the user taps on the circle, you signal the corresponding popup to display. You can even add animations to the popup with blend. If it were me I would tie the pin and the popup together with a matching tag. Then, when you tap the pin, cycle through the UIelements on that layer and look for the matching popup. Then once you have it invoke its visibility. If you download a horrible app I made called walk with pals you can see this very scenario in effect